# How do I debug javascript in visual studio when an asp.net application is run under firefox?

Tags: javascript, debugging

How to debug javascript in visual studio when an asp.net application is run under mozilla firefox browser? IE supports by enabling javascript debug option .

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At the moment, there is no Firefox extension that allows you to debug JavaScript directly in Visual Studio.

Visual Studio 2008 came with a very nice [JavaScript debugger](http://www.asp.net/learn/3.5-videos/video-219.aspx), but you have to use it in Internet Explorer.

For debugging JavaScript on Firefox I highly recommend you [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com/), it's a really good JavaScript debugger...